# How to match java regexp between some '#'?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am facing an issue with the String.replaceFirst method.
I have the following String :

```
String content = "select * from queries 
                 where update_date >= to_timestamp('#date|Date debut|dd/MM/yyyy# 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                 and update_date <= to_timestamp('#date|Date fin|dd/MM/yyyy# 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')";
```

(The two expressions between '#' are dynamically defined).
And I have 2 dates too :

```
String begin = "28/05/2018";
String end = "29/05/2018";
```

Then I would to replace the first expression with begin, and the second with end.

I use :

```
content = content.replaceFirst("#(date)\\|(.*)\\|(.*)#", begin);
content = content.replaceFirst("#(date)\\|(.*)\\|(.*)#", end);
```

Although, replaceFirst takes the last '#' of entire String and I am obtaining:

```
select * from queries where update_date >= to_timestamp('28/05/2018 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

I understand the error but I ask you to help me to find a solution.
Thank you a lot ! Axel.

Comment: If i understood correctly, you want to obtain `'28/05/2018# 23:59:59'`, with the last `#` left in the string? A positive lookahead should work as it doesn't capture, such as `"#(date)\\|(.*)\\|(.*)(?=#)"`. If i understand wrong, you should precise your question.

Comment: I want to obtain `select * from queries where update_date >= to_timestamp('28/05/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and update_date <= to_timestamp('29/05/2018 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If looking for a generic regex for both replacements as your question's code seems to want, this is how to make it work:

the regex for `.*` that captures all characters is `greedy` by default, it means that it will try to capture as many characters as it can. This is why your first replacement replaces all.

You can use the `lazy` quantifier `?` to precise that you want to capture the less characters possible instead of the most.

try:

```
#(date)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)#
```

(or escaped version for your code: `"#(date)\\|(.*?)\\|(.*?)#"`)

[see regex in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XwiqZk/1)

Answer (score 0):

When reading your question, I was not sure whether the text between #s (here I mean "date|Date debut|dd/MM/yyyy" and "date|Date fin|dd/MM/yyyy") were dynamically defined or if you were just explaining that you wanted to dynamically replace the fix contents above with your dynamically defined dates.

So I will give you two answers (and both should work).

1. If the text is fix:
   #date\|Date debut\|dd/MM/yyyy# - for the first range
   #date\|Date fin\|dd/MM/yyyy# - for the second range
2. If the text between # is not fix:
   #[^#]*#

The regex above means find a range of chars that start with a #, than contains any chars except a #, this is what [^#] means, 0 or several times (the *) and ends with a #

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String content = "select * from queries " +
        "where update_date >= to_timestamp('#date|Date debut|dd/MM/yyyy# 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') " +
        "and update_date <= to_timestamp('#date|Date fin|dd/MM/yyyy# 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ;";

    String begin = "28/05/2018";
    String end = "29/05/2018";

    content = content.replaceFirst( "#date\\|[^\\|]*\\|[^#]*#", begin );
    content = content.replaceFirst( "#date\\|[^\\|]*\\|[^#]*#", end );

    System.out.println( content );
```

Here we don't need to use the () and we are matching until our character like | or # matched.